# sapui5 - Datepicker not working in mobile at selecting year or month

Tags: mobile, datepicker, sapui5

In Mobile when i click at year or month to change to a specific one, there is no change at all, like the other years or months are unselectable.

Any ideas or forms to fix this,

```
<DatePicker id="dateDesde" valueFormat="yyyyMMdd" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" placeholder="Ingrese la Fecha de inicio" change="handleChange"/>
```

In Desktop it works just fine.

Tested at Safari mobile and Sap Fiori Client.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this sample [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.DatePicker/preview) work on your mobile devices?
You can check its corresponding coding [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.DatePicker/code)

Comment: It does when we tried from the same link that you provided. But then i downloaded the same code to a Sap cloud platform app and then it does not work.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console?
Are you referring to the sap.m library when using the DatePicker control?
Are you referring to an older sapui5 version in your resource path?

Comment: I just created a new SAPUI5 app on SAP Cloud Platform as “Project from Template” -> “SAPUI5 application”
In the view.xml I added your datepicker-line as seen below:
I did not add any other coding to this default SAPUI5 project template.
This seems to work fine on Safari/iOS mobile here.

Could you please try to also create an empty SAPUI5 app from project template and just add your datepicker-line ?
If possible, please also test on Android and Chrome.

Comment: `<mvc:View controllerName="qxpdatepicker001.controller.View1" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
     displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
     <App>
          <pages>
                <Page title="{i18n>title}">
                     <content>
<DatePicker id="dateDesde" valueFormat="yyyyMMdd" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" placeholder="Ingrese la Fecha de inicio" change="handleChange"/> 
                     </content>
                </Page>
          </pages>
     </App>
</mvc:View>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer did you deploy it to sap fiori launchpad? The problem is when we run the app at portal.